# Comparing Ruby/Rails TimeWithZone Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Apologies if this has already been answered, but I've looked over a few similar questions and haven't quite seen this issue addressed.  I'm trying to compare two TimeWithZone objects one from a created_at from my model and the other is a time.ago object

The created_at datetime object:

```
entry.created_at
=> Mon, 27 Jul 2015 08:47:32 UTC +00:00
```

The time.ago object:

```
1.minute.ago
=> Mon, 27 Jul 2015 10:23:29 UTC +00:00
```

Comparing them returns incorrectly:

```
entry.created_at > 1.minute.ago
=> false
```

or

```
entry.created_at < 1.minute.ago
=> true
```

It seems like it's actually comparing these as strings, if that's true how could I convert them to a comparable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mon, 27 Jul 2015 08:47:32 UTC +00:00` is earlier (therefore less) then `Mon, 27 Jul 2015 10:23:29 UTC +00:00`.

It compares it right.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it makes sense when you say it that way.  I think it's just the way it reads can be confusing.  Like, 'this entry was created less than a minute ago' can make one think it was just created in the last 60 seconds from now.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams yea, working with date/datetime objects is a bit confusing on the whole